# addressing images in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

i noticed that using Blob in database is not a good way to show image.
my images are less than 100KB size .
how can i address them in sqlite database?
and where of the drawable folder should i put them?

this is my db:

this is my database class:

```
public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public final String   path = "data/data/com.example.booktest/databases/";
    public final String   Name = "database";
    public SQLiteDatabase mydb;
    private final Context mycontext;

    public database(Context context) {
        super(context, "database", null, 1);
        mycontext = context;    
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {...}

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {...}


    public void useable() {
            boolean checkdb = checkdb();
            if (checkdb) {
            } else {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                try {
                copydatabase();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {}

        }

    }


    public void open() {...}


    @Override
    public void close() {... }


    public boolean checkdb() {...}


    public void copydatabase() throws IOException {...}
```

Comment: Actually, storing 100KB images in the database [works just fine](http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html).

Comment: @CL. could you tell me what method should i use? and how assign it to imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a typical way, developers usually save images in their apps own private directory.

```
/data/data/app_id/files
```

Therefore, you should also follow this way. So, first create a dedicated directory for those images, called `images` and store all images there.

In database side, you can simply save only their names, for example `photo1.jpg`.

**Notes:**

- For getting a reference to your private directory, use `getFilesDir()` method of your activity.
- For obtaining absolute address of an image, you may need to use this code:

  ```
  File privateDir = getFilesDir();
  File imagesDir = new File(privateDir, "images");
  File image = new File(imagesDir, "photo1.jpg");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Simply download the images in sd card and save the directory in `SQLite` table. Get the path and retrieve the image wherever required.

```
String path = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: what method should i use?